# coldfusion two cfmails in same program crashing

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

In ColdFusion there are two emails in one program.  The first is a receipt to the buyer, and the second is a notification to the seller.

```
<cfmail
          from     = "#session.user#"  
          to       = "#persemail#"          
          password = "#session.password#"
          username = "#session.user#"       
          server   = "localhost"                            
          replyto  = "#session.replyto#"
          subject  = "your receipt "               
          type     = "html"   >  
      
      <cfoutput>#cart2#</cfoutput>
  </cfmail>

  <cfmail
          from     = "#session.user#"  
          to       = "#getlogo.MoxcoEmail1#"          
          password = "#session.password#"
          username = "#session.user#"       
          server   = "localhost"                            
          replyto  = "#session.replyto#"
          subject  = "you have an order"               
          type     = "html"   >  

      <p> You have just received the following order </p>          
      <cfoutput>#cart2#</cfoutput>
  </cfmail>
```

Because I was testing the program, it turns out that the "to" in the first email, "#persemail#", is the same as the "to" in the second email, #getlogo.MoxcoEmail1#.  ColdFusion doesn't like this and returns an error that the "to" field must be present (in the 2nd email).  It works fine if the "to" field is different in the two emails, and that should usually be the case, but we can't count on it.

Does anyone know why cfmail gets tangled in its skirts this way when the "to" is the same, and more important, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that you are using `cfoutput` tags inside your `cfmail` tags.  They are not necessary.  While it is very unlikely that they are causing the problem you describe, it's worth a shot to see what happens if you get rid of them.  Also, what are you looking at that shows you the values of the relevant variables?

Comment: dan, how to I output a variable in cfmail without the cfoutput tags?  do I just enclose it in #?

Comment: `<cfoutput>` or `<cfdump>` will both work.  Put them before the `<cfmail>` tags.

Comment: What version of CF and Java are you running on? Can you reproduce the problem if you reduce it to a minimal cfmail example with 2 `cfmail`s with the same `to` address hard-coded in each? I'm able to send multiple cfmail to the same address in the same request without a problem, so unless you've discovered a bug in a particular release, I suspect the cause is in something you're not showing us, eg some code is setting `getlogo.MoxcoEmail1` to empty, or adding an empty string `getlogo.MoxcoEmail1` to a variable scope of higher precedence, during the request before using it in the second email.

Comment: @SevRoberts  -- These are very sensible suggestions, and I'll try it out soon.  For now I've done an end run by cancelling the 2nd email if the "to" is the same.  Probably they don't need to get both a receipt for their order and a notice that there is an order.  But I would still like to untangle the problem.